# Render to a html page in the same page on click of a button in Ruby on Rails in a particular position

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and i have a requirement to redirect to a html page on click of a button.
On click of Help button i need to show a html page in the same window and it should display in 
in the center of the current window with the previous content same in the top.

My code in erb file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.open('../redmine_portals/Redmine Portals.html', '_self');
    window.moveTo(10, 20);
</script>
```

Please help me how do it, refer image.

[image]

Thanks

Sekhar

Comment: you want to do it by ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest with some JS, you render a partial.

So for example:

```
<button onclick="showPartial()">Click me</button>

<%= render partial: "pathto/partial"%>
```

and within the partial I'd have something that you'd show with the JS